AWS ECS: Running hundreds of different algorithms in AWS ECS
I've been studying AWS ECS, but I cannot understand how to architect the following scenario:
I'm trying to run hundreds of algorithms at once in real-time:

Each algorithm needs to run in a single isolated container
Algorithms share the same common code / environment setup and only
one file is different in each algorithm (let's call it the
"algo-file") which contains some custom code that differs from all
other algorithms
Algorithms are long running - they should be
perpetually live until they get a termination signal from a main
instance that I have built If an algorithm's container fails, the
ECS should replace it with a healthy container
No two "algo-files" are same across algorithms, even though all other files are the same
I keep track of which "algo-files" have been deployed (and which
have not) in a central database
Each container should also be able
to interact with a common database and call external APIs and
receive requests from internal EC2 instances.

So far, my understanding of the docs points to having one ECS Service per algorithm - which each Service running one container. I'm not sure if this is the right way to use ECS because it looks like a Service is meant to run multiple containers at once.
Any suggestions on how this may be architected?

I wonder if you can have a common container, pass in a parameter, on startup fetch the algorithm file from an S3 bucket based on the parameter value.

Why fetch? Just pack all the files into a single container image and then use a parameter to select one.

True. I guess fetching is more extensible, but if it's a static set then building them into the container makes sense.
